# Flex 4.6 time picker component?

Tags: apache-flex, air, timer

Is there any component is used as time picker in Adobe flex4.6 or AIR.I need to get time as input.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the Mobile DateSpinner; but I don't think there is a desktop version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just slap two numeric steppers together.

```
<s:NumericStepper id="dateHour" minimum="0" maximum="23" value="{_someDate.getHours()}" />
<s:NumericStepper id="dateMinute" minimum="0" maximum="59" valueFormatFunction="{leadingZero}" value="{_someDate.getMinutes()}"/>
```

and the leading zero function,

```
public static function leadingZero(value:Number):String
{
    if(value < 10){
        return "0" + value;
    }
    return value.toString();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the Flex3 control.
http://joelhooks.com/2008/10/11/flex-date-and-time-datetime-picker-control/